# git: cherry-pick fails to fix branch from master using Gerrit Code Review

Tags: git, merge, gerrit, rebase, cherry-pick

It turns out that another developer had avoided merging some changes until they could be vetted on master, so it was good that it got flagged.  However, I manually applied my changes.  I believe that I made a mistake here by not using merge, but rather applying a patch.

Now that those missing changes are applied (also via patch) and the files are identical, I am assuming that some git merge and/or rebase command needs to be executed to mark the files are now back in-sync between the master and fix branch?

Looking at the following tutorials, it is still not clear to me as to how to resolve this:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

What does seem clear is that rebase will not work correctly, as there is development work on master that probably shouldn't be moved into the fix branch, but those changes are in directories that are not currently utilized by the fix branch.  Also, the fix branch should maintain a history of all commits.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Or alternatively, what do you want to avoid/resolve?

Comment: I would like to get the branch back to the state where cherry-picks will work again.  Thanks.